# Short Story About a Mystical Bog and Illicit Affair Involving a Professor

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

It was in an anthology of short stories published prior to 1999 and written by a woman, maybe with the first name Anne, but I'm not certain.
I recall her going into detail about beetles copulating in the woods but that's as much as I remember.

I just loved the pacing and tone of the story and Google for it every few years but haven't for the life of me been able to find it.